# JSON.parse not running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My JSON.parse line of code is not running properly. Any ideas? On the run of the function 'showconsultationdata', 2 alert boxes should be shown, but my 2nd alert box doesn't run because the running of the program always stops at the JSON.parse line.
Here is my AJAX script.

```
function showconsultationdata(str) { //face e.g and checkboxes for that date selected.
var xmlhttp;
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert("hi");
          document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;             
          var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          document.getElementById("test").value=a.first;
          alert("bye");
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

Here is my BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php file.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('Config/Js.php');
$q = $_GET['q'];
$consult="SELECT * FROM Counsel where nric='$_SESSION[nric]' and dateconsulted='$q'";
$consultresult = mysqli_query($dbconn,$consult);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultresult)) {
$queryResult[] = $row['skincareremarks'];
$queryResult[] = $row['skinconditionremarks'];
}
$skincareremarks = $queryResult[0];
$skinconditionremarks = $queryResult[1];
echo json_encode(array('first'=>$skincareremarks,'second'=>$skinconditionremarks));
```

Oh i tried alerting out the xmlhttp.responseText, and this is what i got.
[image]
As you can see, in the last line, it shows the response text value correctly. But im not sure why it is showing my javascripts svc

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Define running properly. What string returned by script

Comment: 1) Take advantage of mysqli's parameter binding. As it is, you are wide open for SQL injection attacks, and the `$_SESSION` variable could be throwing things off. 2) What is the value of `xmlhttp.responseText`? I bet it's not coming back as valid.

Comment: Take advantage of the browser console. F12

Comment: @yuriy636 i got this error. VM95:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange @ BAConsult.php:472 not sure why

Comment: @E_p as i've said in my post, it doesnt run that line of code, the 2nd alert box should appear but it didnt. This is the string returned when i echoed it out {"first":"skincare test","second":"skincondition test"}

Comment: @KevinB i got this {"first":"skincare test","second":"skincondition test"}

Comment: pass one more parameter in json_encode(array('first'=>$skincareremarks,'second'=>$skinconditionremarks), 1)

Comment: @AfshanShujat Thanks, but it didn't work, i think it has got to do with what i screenshotted. My javascript SRCs are appearing in my xhtml.responseText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve to problem by filtering out what was being shown in my xmlhttp.responseText.

in my BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php file, i did this.

```
echo "<div id='test1'>";
echo json_encode(array('first'=>$skincareremarks,'second'=>$skinconditionremarks));
echo "</div>";
```

I gave this output a div called 'test1'.

Then, in my main file's AJAX script, i did this.

```
var a = JSON.parse($(xmlhttp.responseText).filter('#test1').html());    
document.getElementById("test").value=a.first;
```

So basically, it filters out the rest of the xhtmlhttp.responseText outputs, and selects only the div id='test1'.

Hope this helps those who have this problem too..

Answer (score 0):

> But im not sure why it is showing my javascripts svc

`include('Config/Js.php');` Because your included script might echo them? Those adding HTML to the response causing it to become invalid JSON.

Comment: Yeah im thinking that it is that too. Do you know how i can place several SRCs in a php file because my other javascript functions uses other SRCs. I've tried the defer method in <script> but it doesn't work..

Comment: In your code I don't see a reason to use `include('Config/Js.php');`  just reomve the line.

Comment: If i remove that line, my AJAX and button won't work because there is no SRC for the javascript function. I think that there is a way to select a specific data from the responseText i want. But im not sure how to do that.